# How to convert a sub-dict to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, subdirectory, praw

When I do this

```
subm = reddit.user.karma()
print(subm)
```

I get this kind of dictionary:

```
{Subreddit(display_name='AskReddit'): {'comment_karma': 1308, 'link_karma': 4}, Subreddit(display_name='food'): {'comment_karma': 67, 'link_karma': 72}, Subreddit(display_name='Documentaries'): {'comment_karma': 128, 'link_karma': 2}, Subreddit(display_name='explainlikeimfive'): {'comment_karma': 2, 'link_karma': 1},}
```

How I can convert it into DF?
What ever I have tried is not working, as I always get error `TypeError: 'Subreddit' object is not iterable`  `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Subreddit object`

From PRAW docs:

> The returned dict contains subreddits as keys. Each subreddit key contains a sub-dict that have keys for comment_karma and link_karma. The dict is sorted in descending karma order.
> Note: Each key of the main dict is an instance of Subreddit. It is recommended to iterate over the dict in order to retrieve the values, preferably through dict.items().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=subm.values(), index=(key.display_name for key in subm.keys()))
```

You will get a DataFrame with keys of original sub-dicts as columns, and `display_name` of each Subreddit object as index.
You can always switch index and columns of the DataFrame using `.T` property.

Comment: Hey Enrico, 
thanks, quick and efficient. Also appreciate explanation and the tip for the transpose option.